# Converting Postman Json body request to Jmeter body request

Tags: json, jmeter, postman, performance-testing, beanshell

```js
var moment = require("moment");
var time = moment().valueOf();
pm.environment.set('time', time);


var eventArray = [];_
for(var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) 
{  
 
var t = time + (i * 1000);
    eventArray.push({
      "eid": i,
      "time": t
    });
} 

var data = { "event":  eventArray };
var JSONData = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)).toString();
pm.environment.set("JSONData", JSONData);
console.log("JSONDATA", JSONData);
```

Change your entire request body to the following variable:

{{JSONData}}

This is what would be sent:

{“event”:[{“eid”:1,“time”:1538518294839},{“eid”:2,“time”:1538518295839},{“eid”:3,“time”:1538518296839},{“eid”:4,“time”:1538518297839},{“eid”:5,“time”:1538518298839},{“eid”:6,“time”:1538518299839},{“eid”:7,“time”:1538518300839},{“eid”:8,“time”:1538518301839},{“eid”:9,“time”:1538518302839},{“eid”:10,“time”:1538518303839},{“eid”:11,“time”:1538518304839},{“eid”:12,“time”:1538518305839},{“eid”:13,“time”:1538518306839},{“eid”:14,“time”:1538518307839},{“eid”:15,“time”:1538518308839},{“eid”:16,“time”:1538518309839},{“eid”:17,“time”:1538518310839},{“eid”:18,“time”:1538518311839},{“eid”:19,“time”:1538518312839},{“eid”:20,“time”:1538518313839},{“eid”:21,“time”:1538518314839},{“eid”:22,“time”:1538518315839},{“eid”:23,“time”:1538518316839},{“eid”:24,“time”:1538518317839},{“eid”:25,“time”:1538518318839},{“eid”:26,“time”:1538518319839},{“eid”:27,“time”:1538518320839},{“eid”:28,“time”:1538518321839},{“eid”:29,“time”:1538518322839},{“eid”:30,“time”:1538518323839},{“eid”:31,“time”:1538518324839},{“eid”:32,“time”:1538518325839},{“eid”:33,“time”:1538518326839},{“eid”:34,“time”:1538518327839},{“eid”:35,“time”:1538518328839},{“eid”:36,“time”:1538518329839},{“eid”:37,“time”:1538518330839},{“eid”:38,“time”:1538518331839},{“eid”:39,“time”:1538518332839},{“eid”:40,“time”:1538518333839},{“eid”:41,“time”:1538518334839},{“eid”:42,“time”:1538518335839},{“eid”:43,“time”:1538518336839},{“eid”:44,“time”:1538518337839},{“eid”:45,“time”:1538518338839},{“eid”:46,“time”:1538518339839},{“eid”:47,“time”:1538518340839},{“eid”:48,“time”:1538518341839},{“eid”:49,“time”:1538518342839},{“eid”:50,“time”:1538518343839}]}

Now i need the above request to be converted as jmeter request and pass in a single variable.

Comment: {
    "event": [
        {
            "eid": 1,
            "time": 1653398573082
        },
        {
            "eid": 2,
            "time": 1653398574082
        },
        {
            "eid": 3,
            "time": 1653398575082
        },
        {
            "eid": 4,
            "time": 1653398576082
        },
        {
            "eid": 5,
            "time": 1653398577082
        }
    ]
}

Comment: hi @dimitri i am asking u that the { bracket should not come at the starting of the object

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent Groovy code for using in a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) would be something like:

```
def events = []

def time = System.currentTimeMillis()

1.upto(50, {
    events.add([eid: it, time: time + it * 1000])
})

def JSONData = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([event: events]).toPrettyString()

vars.put('JSONData', JSONData)
```

The generated value can be accessed as `${JSONData}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)